# How to automate check variable existence in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, gulp-plugin

I have react components which render variables through props.

**main.jsx**

```
<div>
   {props.name && <h1>{props.name}</h1>}
   {props.id && <h1>{props.id}</h1>}
</div>
```

**personal.jsx**

```
<div>
   {props.city && <h1>{props.city}</h1>}
   {props.country && <h1>{props.country}</h1>}
</div>
```

the same files repeated in in multiple looks whose styles are different.

The structure look likes.

```
--Card-1
  --main.jsx
  --personal.jsx
--Card-2
  --main.jsx
  --personal.jsx
--Card-3
  --main.jsx
  --personal.jsx
--Card-4
  --main.jsx
  --personal.jsx
```

This may increase in future. I want to check/automate script to check `name and id` exits in evary main.js and `city and country` exist in every personal.jsx file

Answer (score -1):

You could use bash script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
PERSONAL_COUNT=$(find . -name "personal.jsx" | wc -l)
CITY_COUNT=$(grep "props.city" **/personal.jsx | wc -l)
COUNTRY_COUNT=$(grep "props.country" **/personal.jsx | wc -l)
MAIN_COUNT=$(find . -name "main.jsx" | wc -l)
ID_COUNT=$(grep "props.id" **/main.jsx | wc -l)
NAME_COUNT=$(grep "props.name" **/main.jsx | wc -l)

[[ $MAIN_COUNT == $NAME_COUNT ]] && echo 'name: OK' || echo 'name: Too less name prop usage in main.jsx files' && exit 1
[[ $MAIN_COUNT == $ID_COUNT ]] && echo 'id: OK' || echo 'id: Too less name prop usage in main.jsx files' && exit 1
[[ $PERSONAL_COUNT == $CITY_COUNT ]] && echo 'city: OK' || echo 'city: Too less name prop usage in main.jsx files' && exit 1
[[ $PERSONAL_COUNT == $COUNTRY_COUNT ]] && echo 'country: OK' || echo 'country: Too less name prop usage in main.jsx files' && exit 1
```

Comment: But I want to check the variables  used in that files with some automation work.

Comment: @Mr.Pandya I've edited the response. Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for response. But alignment of city and country may change. Rendering the properties is not consistent. Every card look view is different .I have mentioned only two properties. There may be 5 props. How can I check these all are used in every file and if any one of not used in file we need show error like these variable not used in Card-3 main.jsx file

Comment: If you are pointing towards testing, probably use ui testing framework like selenium and assert against the values in each of the cards.

Comment: Selenium falls under integration testing. But my problem is not that.

Comment: @Mr.Pandya Is that script file is something you looking for?

Comment: Yes. Gulp script or something like that @MaciejTrojniarz

Comment: @Mr.Pandya The script above will exit with error (exit 1) <- which should inform the CI/CD task that something went wrong